# Process two nearly identical JSON blocks with one set of code

Tags: javascript, json

My goal is to send JSON returned from an API request to Slack. My code works when I send JSON of one content type. However, I need to accomplish this for two content types. I would like to efficiently parse the JSON for the two content types and use a single block of code to send the JSON to Slack. Examples below illustrate.

### JSON block 1 - `Content`

```
{
    "Content": {
        "CreatedByUser": {
            "DisplayName": "<username>",
            "ProfileUrl": "<profileurl>"
        },
        "HtmlName": "<name>",
        "HtmlDescription": "<html>",
        "Url": "<url>"
    }
}
```

### JSON block 2 - `Comment`

Note that JSON block 1 is nested:

```
{
    "Comment": {
        "Content": {
            "CreatedByUser": {
                "DisplayName": "<username>",
                "ProfileUrl": "<profileurl>"
            },
            "HtmlName": "<name>",
            "HtmlDescription": "<html>",
            "Url": "<url>"
        }
    }
}
```

### JS code that parses and perform actions

This shows my current code that deals *only* with **JSON block 1**.

The values are extracted:

```
var request = require('request');

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);

        var username = info.Content.CreatedByUser.Username;
        var profileUrl = info.Content.CreatedByUser.ProfileUrl;
        var subject = info.Content.HtmlName;
        var url = info.Content.Url
        var text = info.Content.HtmlDescription;
    };
```

All values are sent to Slack:

```
    function sendToSlack(theUsername, theIconEmoji) {
        var payload = {
            attachments: [{
                author_name: username,
                author_link: profileUrl,
                title: subject,
                title_link: url,
                text: text
            }]
        };
        var theRequest = {
            url: urlWebHook,
            method: "POST",
            json: payload
        };
        request(theRequest, function (error, response, body) { });
    }
    var urlWebHook = "<webhook url>";
    sendToSlack();
```

Rather, I would like the code to process *both* JSON blocks 1 and 2 without duplicating code. For example, I believe I can do something like:

```
if (info.hasOwnProperty('Content')) {

    var username = info.Content.CreatedByUser.Username;
    var profileUrl = info.Content.CreatedByUser.ProfileUrl;
    var subject = info.Content.HtmlName;
    var url = info.Content.Url
    var text = info.Content.HtmlDescription;
};

if (info.Comment.hasOwnProperty('Content')) {

    var username = info.Comment.CreatedByUser.Username;
    var profileUrl = info.Content.CreatedByUser.ProfileUrl;
    var subject = info.Comment.HtmlName;
    var url = info.Comment.Url
    var text = info.Comment.Body;
};
```

...followed by the code to send the JSON to Slack.

(I know the above is inaccurate -- I am just trying to communicate my thinking.)

But, if I understand correctly and based on experimentation, that would require me to duplicate the "send to Slack" code inside each `if` clause because, if the variables are outside an `if` clause, they are not otherwise recognized as defined. Instead, I would like to use the "send to Slack" code one time only for simpler maintenance and cleaner code.

I am new to JavaScript. I am stuck at this point and would be grateful for any guidance.

Comment: In block 2 is Comment supposed to be inside Content or the other way?

Comment: Variables declared with `var` are treated as if they were declared at the very top of the containing function.

Comment: @Scimonster Unfortunately it is accurate as it is shown

Comment: The structure isn't a problem, but it was unclear when your code showed `if (info.Content.hasOwnProperty('Comment')) {` as if it was the other way.

Comment: @hcdocs where you getting/calling info from? Is it used later in the sendToSlack function?

Comment: @Scimonster Thank you for pointing this out, I have edited the question for clarity

Comment: @basic I am receiving it from a webhook by [Telligent CMS platform](https://community.telligent.com/community/10/w/api-documentation/61380/rest-api-documentation) -- the flow of information is content post by a Telligent user > webhook > JavaScript Azure Function > Slack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pointy commented, variables declared with `var` are treated as if they were declared at the very top of the containing function. This is as opposed to variables declared with `let` in ES6. So your code as-is should actually work. You may want to define the variables without setting them before the `if`, as some people don't like declaring `var`s in an if block:

```
var username, profileUrl, subject, url, text;
if (info.hasOwnProperty('Content')) {

    username = info.Content.CreatedByUser.Username;
    profileUrl = info.Content.CreatedByUser.ProfileUrl;
    subject = info.Content.HtmlName;
    url = info.Content.Url
    text = info.Content.HtmlDescription;
};

if (info.hasOwnProperty('Comment')) {

    username = info.Comment.CreatedByUser.Username;
    profileUrl = info.Content.CreatedByUser.ProfileUrl;
    subject = info.Comment.HtmlName;
    url = info.Comment.Url
    text = info.Comment.Body;
};
```

To make it more efficient, you can extract the values only once by changing what variable they are pulling from:

```
var content;
if (info.hasOwnProperty('Content')) {
    content = info.Content;
}
if (info.hasOwnProperty('Comment')) {
    content = info.Comment.Content;
}

var username = content.CreatedByUser.Username;
var profileUrl = content.CreatedByUser.ProfileUrl;
var subject = content.HtmlName;
var url = content.Url
var text = content.HtmlDescription;
```